# how to remove JMenu.addSeparator() after it is being called

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jseparator

Hello guys,

I just want to ask something if is it possible to remove `JMenu.addSeparator()` after it is being called? for example in my form there is a menu bar and inside the menu bar lets say there are three `JmenuItems` and each of it has `JMenu.addSeparator()`. What i want to do is, if a different user is log in I want to `setVisible(false)` one of `JMenuItem` because that particular user in not authorize to use that `JMenuItem`. The problem is when I `setVisible(false)` one of the `JMenuItem` the `JMenu.addSeparator()` still exist which kinda awkward to watch since there are no `JMenuItem` exist in the middle of two `JMenu.addSeparator()`. Hope you can help me with this problem. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: It might be easier to rebuild the menu from scratch per user

Comment: what do you mean rebuild the menu from scratch?

Comment: I mean just that.  When a user is logged in, rather the "hiding" or "showing" menu items, you would rebuild the entire `JMenu` from scratch, only adding those menu items that the current user can actually use...

Comment: Actually that was my first thought, but i was thinking it might be easier if i just do the "hiding" or "showing" menu items that the current user can actually use.

Comment: So, then you would need to walk the `JMenu` check to see if two `JSeparator`s reside next to each other instead...I know, personally, what would be easier for me ;)

Comment: thats why i will follow your advice because i know that i still have a lot to learn and a long road to walk because i'm still a newb in this language, but anyway thanks for your advice hope your always there to help those who do not know everthing about this language..=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two possible solutions...

### You Could...

Remove the contents of the menu and rebuilt it based on what the user can do...

```
menu.removeAll();
// Add menu items back in...
// Personally, I'd have some method that could return back all
// the JMenuItems that could appear on this menu based on the
// the user...
```

This would be my preferred solution...

### You Could...

Hide/show the menu items based on what the current user can actually do and then remove all the `JSeparator`s that appear next to each other, for example...

```
Component last = null;
for (Component comp : menu.getComponents()) {
    if (comp instanceof JSeparator && last instanceof JSeparator) {
        menu.remove(comp);
    } else {
        last = comp;
    }
}
```

Personally, I know which I would prefer and generally, which would produce consistent results...

Comment: thats one of my problem since the structure of my code is not consistent which i can hardly produce consistent results. Because i'm not following the proper build up of codes which is very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a situation where I had to remove the separator from an existing menu.  (Old code and wasn't allowed to refactor the whole mess.)

So I used the idea of MadProgrammer's 2nd solution - but rewrote it to actually work.

```
        Component last = null;
        for (int idx = 0; (idx < m_fileMenu.getMenuComponentCount()); idx++) {
            Component comp = m_fileMenu.getMenuComponent(idx);
            if (comp instanceof JPopupMenu.Separator && last instanceof JPopupMenu.Separator) {
                m_fileMenu.remove(comp);
                idx--;
            } else {
                last = comp;
            }
        }
```